# ENOENT error when trying to install Yeoman from npm

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, windows-7-x64

I am trying to install Yeoman using the following command in cmd:

```
npm install --global yo
```

I get the following:

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\{userdir}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--global" "yo"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.0
npm ERR! path C:\{userDIr}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:{userDir}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\{userDir}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\{userDir}\npm-debug.log
```

The following are installed:

- Node.js v4.4.4
- npm v2.15.1, v3.9.0 (I tried with both versions, I had exactly the same output message)

and my PC runs on Windows 7 x64.

**Solutions I tried:**

1. I run

   **npm cache clear**

but no luck.

2. I uninstalled and reinstalled node.js, but nothing changed either.
3. I also tried the following:

   - deleted the node_modules folder
   - deleted C:\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache folder
   - unchecked and applied Read-only in the properties for C:\AppData\Roaming\npm folder
4. I read all the answers to related problems here, but nothing helped.

Before that, I successfully installed **bower** v1.7.9 and **grunt** v1.2.0 with npm, executing

```
npm install --global yo bower grunt-cli
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10312 and https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/437 the issue is **yo v1.8.2** .

Executing

```
npm install --global yo@1.8.1
```

instead of

```
npm install --global yo
```

solved the problem, although there will probably be a hotfix released soon.